# Django: не отображаются изображения

Tags: html, django, изображения, url

Понемногу работаю над университетским проектом: решил написать интернет-магазин на Django. Почти сделана домашняя страница, лендинг и недавно начата работа над страницей товара, как вдруг джанго напрочь отказался отображать изображения на всех страницах (версию джанго не обновлял, текущая - 2.0.2). Советы настроить `static` не помогли.

[image: Homepage]
[image: Product page]

**settings.py**

```
`STATIC_URL = '/static/'
 STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static',),)
 MEDIA_URL = '/static/media/'
 MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')`
```

**models.py**
[Модуль models.py](https://github.com/archeski/bookstore/blob/master/goods/models.py)

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'goods/(?P<item_id>\w+)/$', views.item, name='item'),

 ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Для другого application'a я использовал path вместо url чтобы получить item_id.

**item.html**

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <img class="row">
            {% for img in item.item.itemimage_set.all %}
                <img src="{{ img.image.url }}" class="image-responsive">
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <h1 class="text-center">
                {{ item.item.name }}
            </h1>
            <div class="">
                <p>
                     Price: {{ item.item.price }} $
                    {% if item.item.discount != 0 %}
                        Discount: - {{ item.item.discount }}%
                    {% endif %}
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="">
                {{ item.item.description }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Аналогично и для других страниц в application'ах ссылку на изображение я беру из БД, прим.`{{ image.image.url }}`

Comment: `MEDIA_URL` не должен быть дочерним `STATIC_URL`

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev ранее и вовсе этих настроек у меня не было всё работало и отображалось корректно. media папка лежала в static

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev вынесение media из static в окружение ничего не дало